# Disable logs for specific file, firebug

Tags: debugging, web, firebug, mozilla

I'm trying to debug a small piece of functionality, however the firebug console is giving me lots of logs from different files and I don't care about those at all.

Is there a way to tell firebug to ignore logs/warning/errors from chosen files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do so in Firebug, but there is already an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2955) filed, which requests this feature.

It's still unclear how the UI should look like, so you can make a suggestion there.

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about firebug but you can do that in Google Chrome. In the 'Inspect Elements' window right click on any line that you don't like to be logged, there will be menu with 'Filter' option and you can choose the file to filter for logging.